# The user specified as a definer does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

> Error Number: 1449
>
> The user specified as a definer
> ('cpses_whsovxoeji'@'localhost') does
> not exist
>
> INSERT INTO `users` (`UsersEmail`,
> `UsersTime`, `UsersStatus`,
> `UsersTimeZone`, `UsersTypeAccount`,
> `UsersChannel`) VALUES ('',
> 1405079020, '1', '-180', 1,
> 'e9bd75c277b4b811d046ebe5f041d670')

Не совсем понимаю, на что ругается, возможно, нет прав для текущего пользователя?
И откуда cpses_whsovxoeji'@'localhost

Comment: Пользуясь волшебным сервисом http://translate.google.com

> The user specified as a definer ('cpses_whsovxoeji'@'localhost') does not exist

=

> Указанный в качестве определителя ('cpses_whsovxoeji "@" локальный ") пользователь не существует

Запросом затрагивается сущность, принадлежащая этому пользователю, которого не существует.

Ссылки по теме из простейшего запроса в гугл.

http://goo.gl/JHe2qu
http://goo.gl/3cuvcf  
http://goo.gl/TvDS0n

Comment: Дело в том, почему от имени этого пользователя происходит вставка? я его впервые вижу в системе

Comment: Смотрю, что в Mysql нет такого пользователя и в дампе Sql, где создается процедура Insert.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, что значит "создается процедура insert"? Вообще скорее всего дело в триггере.

> Смотрю, что в Mysql нет такого пользователя

учитывая то, что именно на это он и ругается - неудивительно.

Comment: Во вкладке phpmyadmin "Состояние" активные 1 пользователь

     7795 cpses_whbBI9GlHN localhost Нет Sleep 0

Вопрос, почему все процессы выполняются не от созданного мной, единственного пользователя root_oleg?

Comment: В триггере, который срабатывает при Insert Users? Нашел в триггере Определитель с этим именем. Изменю на пользователя в системе.